# ASP.NET MVC - Get log in status of a user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my application, I would like to check whether or not a particular user is logged in or not so I can display a status saying that that user is either "online" or "offline" to another user. This question is **not** about authenticating a user, only about getting the authentication status of a user.

How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in field that can be used for this. I would recommend creating a custom boolean field in your database on the `AspNetUsers` table. Set it to true when they login and false when they logout.

Comment: @DrewKennedy would that work if someone doesn't physically sign out, but instead closes the tab or browser, or navigates to another website?

Comment: That was a limitation I had in mind when I suggested that. The answer is I highly doubt it. This may have to be something done with JavaScript, but I can't provide a firm answer.

Comment: @DrewKennedy Now that you mention JavaScript, I might have to do something along the lines of tracking if a user is "active" and working around that. Similar to websites which sign you out of 30mins of inactivity

Comment: I can't be sure, but I wouldn't be surprised if they use WebSockets (SignalR, for example).

Comment: @DrewKennedy Hmm, I always assumed that they just track whether or not your mouse moves or keyboard strokes are occurring, and if not they signed you out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think an option is to use some real-time solutions. [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) for example.
When a user logs in , you connect it to the hub. OnConnected() action save its state.Then OnDisconnected() remove from "OnlineRepository".

**Update with example**
Here is how I did this in a asp.Net Mvc 5 app.

- A Model class that holds a single user like:

  ```
      public class SingleConnection 
      {
          public SingleConnection()
          {
              ConnectionId = new List();
          }
          public string Id { get; set; }
          public List ConnectionId { get; set; }
      }
  ```
- A connection mapping class that helps in adding/removeing and getting a user from list

  ```
      public class ConnectionMapping
      {
          private readonly List _connections = new List();
          public int Count
          {
              get
              {
                  return _connections.Count;
              }
          }
          public void Add(string key, string connectionId)
          {
              lock (_connections)
              {
                  var sn = _connections.Where(x => x.Id == key).FirstOrDefault();
                  if (sn != null) // there is a connection with this key
                  {
                      _connections.Find(x => x.Id == key).ConnectionId.Add(connectionId);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      _connections.Add(new SingleConnection { Id = key, ConnectionId = new List { connectionId } });
                  }
              }
          }
          public List GetConnections(string id)
          {
              var con = _connections.Find(x => x.Id == id);
              return con != null ?  con.ConnectionId : new List();
          }
          public List AllConnectionIds() 
          {
              List results = new List();
               var allItems = _connections.Where(x => x.ConnectionId.Count > 0).ToList();
               foreach (var item in allItems)
               {
                   results.AddRange(item.ConnectionId);
               }
               return results;
          }
          public List AllKeys() 
          {
              return _connections.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
          }
          public void Remove(string key, string connectionId)
          {
              lock (_connections)
              {
                  var item = _connections.Find(x => x.Id == key);
                  if (_connections.Find(x => x.Id == key) != null)
                  {
                      _connections.Find(x => x.Id == key).ConnectionId.Remove(connectionId);
                      if (_connections.Find(x => x.Id == key).ConnectionId.Count == 0)
                      {
                          _connections.Remove(item);
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  ```

  - In my Hub Class

  ```
  private void IsActive(string connection, bool connected) 
  {
      Clients.All.clientconnected(connection, connected);
  }
  public override Task OnConnected()
  {
      string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
      _connections.Add(name, Context.ConnectionId);
      IsActive(name, true);
      return base.OnConnected();
  }
  public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
  {
      string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
      _connections.Remove(name, Context.ConnectionId);
      IsActive(name, false);
      return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
  }
  public override Task OnReconnected()
  {
      string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
      if (!_connections.GetConnections(name).Contains(Context.ConnectionId))
      {
          _connections.Add(name, Context.ConnectionId);
      }
      IsActive(name, false);
      return base.OnReconnected();
  }
  ```
- In _Layout.cshtml

  ```
  // reference scripts
  // add a callback or the OnConnected() Will not fire
  chat.client.clientconnected = function (id,active){
  /*
  this will be called everytime a user connect or disconnect to the hub
  */
  }
  $.connection.hub.start();
  ```

Now with this I get in realtime all users that are online.
**Note:** This is an InMemory solution. Other solutions are [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections)

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, as well as @DrewKennedy, I'll look in to it!

Comment: Ok then,I will add a simple solution now here so you know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I would create my own system to define what are your "active" users:

- You can keep the track of your users with a dictionary stored in the [System.Web.Caching.Cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache(v=vs.110).aspx) class.
- In your base controller (because it would be instantiate for any
  client request) insert the current user to your cached dictionary
  by calling the KeepTrackActiveUsers method.
- Add the SetInactiveUser method to your logout method.

{

```
private Dictionary<int,DateTime> ActiveUsers
{
    get 
    { 
      if(Cache["ActiveUsers"] == null)
        Cache["ActiveUsers"] = new Dictionary<int,DateTime>();
      return Cache["ActiveUsers"];
    } 
    set { Cache["ActiveUsers"] = value; }
}

private void KeepTrackActiveUsers()
{
    ActiveUsers[CurrentUserId] = DateTime.Now;
}   

private const int expirationTime = 600;   
private IEnumerable<int> GetActiveUsers()
{       
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    ActiveUsers = ActiveUsers
        .Where(x => now.Subtract(x.Value).TotalSeconds < expirationTime)
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
    return ActiveUsers.Keys;
}

private void SetInactiveUser()
{
    ActiveUsers.Remove(CurrentUserId);
}

//to be defined
private int CurrentUserId
{
    get { return default(int); }
}
```